# How do you initialize RolapStars for a distributed cache?

Tags: mondrian

I need create a distributed cache for Mondrian so I looked at a hazelcast cache implementation https://github.com/webdetails/cdc/blob/master/src/pt/webdetails/cdc/mondrian/SegmentCacheHazelcast.java#L141

It warns:

> All relevant RolapStars must have been initialized inside mondrian for this to work.

How do I initialize the the relevant RolapStars?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run a dumb MDX query on each cube. Should do the trick.

```
select [Measures].[Foo] on columns from [Bar]
```